# Use ITempDataDictionay class in Asp.net Core project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have a TestResult class which is inherited from ActionResult class as you can see in the code below.

```
public class TestResult : ActionResult
{
    public ActionResult InnerResult { get; set; }

    public TestResult(ActionResult innerResult)
    {
        InnerResult = innerResult;
    }

    public override void ExecuteResult(ActionContext context)
    {
        var tempDataService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<ITempDataDictionary>();
        tempDataService.AddTestObject(new TestClass("TestValue1", "TestValue1"));
        tempDataService.AddTestString("TestString1");
        InnerResult.ExecuteResult(context);
    }
}
```

i have two objects one is TestClass another one is a random string , i add them to tempDataService, the implementation of the AddTestObject and AddTestString methods is in the code below :

```
 public static class TestExtensions
{
    const string TestObject1 = "_Test1";
    const string TestObject2 = "_Test2";

    public static void AddTestObject(this ITempDataDictionary tempData, TestClass testClass)
    {
        if (!tempData.ContainsKey(TestObject1))
        {
            tempData[TestObject1] = new List<TestClass>();
        }
        ((List<TestClass>)tempData[TestObject1]).Add(testClass);
    }

    public static void AddTestString(this ITempDataDictionary tempData,string testString)
    {
        tempData[TestObject2] = testString;
    }

    public static ActionResult WithTestMessages(this ActionResult result)
    {
        return new TestResult(result);
    }
}
```

now i have a TestController with two actions as you can see below :

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private readonly ITempDataDictionary _tempDataDictionary;

    public TestController(ITempDataDictionary tempDataDictionary)
    {
        _tempDataDictionary = tempDataDictionary;
    }

    public IActionResult TestAction()
    {
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(TestAction2)).WithTestMessages();
    }

    public IActionResult TestAction2()
    {
        return Content("TestAction2");
    }
}
```

the strange thing here is that if i inject the ITempDataDictionary in a controller and go through the QuickWatch window and see the _tempDataDictionary value there is not anything for the TestObject1 and i just see the TestObject2 , the point is that in TestObject1 i expect to see the class object and in the TestObject2 i expect to see the string value.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, in the current implementation `ITempDataDictionary` accepts only primitive values. So you can workaround it by serializing and then deserializing your collection `List<TestClass>()` to json.

Comment: thank you , yeah i found that and like you said i use jsonConverter to do the implementation.